# Jenkins config copy : windows platform

Tags: jenkins

I would like to copy the configurations of Jenkins server(on windows) to another on Jenkins server (on Windows platform ).Can any one help how to do it?

Comment: jenkins configuration settings are platform independent. Steps (see below)will be same for moving to any new server.

Answer (score 1):

Did you  try [Job import plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Job%20Import%20Plugin)?  It can import one or many projects. It probably takes care of required plugins as well.

My next try will be to copy jenkins home from one machine to another.  If you do not have much history this will be quick. (Or you could copy only corresponding /config.xml and nextBuild files)

You may use [SCM Sync configuration plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/SCM%20Sync%20configuration%20plugin) for backup and moving configuration onto new machine..

Answer (score 1):

[Job import plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Job+Import+Plugin) do the work for you, I have used it many times. It works similar to copying the config.xml and nextBuild files, but it gives you a convenient interface to choose which jobs you want to transfer.

However you need to take care of all installed Jenkins plugins yourself.